# RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log numpy

Tags: python, numpy, logging

I am currently trying to code a spam filtering spam , ham using Naive Bayesian.

```
   ham_class = np.log(ham / data_size)  #
            spam_class = np.log(spam / data_size)
            log_class_priors = np.array([ham_class, spam_class])
```

However, the part above is giving me running time problem. The message as an output is giving me :

```
    RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
      ham_class = np.log(ham / data_size)  #
    
    RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
      ham_sums = np.log(ham_sums)
    
    RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
      spam_sums = np.log(spam_sums)
```

Result of the numpy array :

```
    *[-inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf
      -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf
      -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf
      -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf]
     [-inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf
      -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf
      -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf
      -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf -inf]]*
```

Comment: No MCVE without sample inputs. Unable to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ham_class = np.log(ham / data_size)

**data_size** has at least 1 zero or **ham / data_size** outputs at least 1 zero(in other words, ham or data_size has a zero element) or **ham / data_size** is zero.

> ham_sums = np.log(ham_sums)

**ham_sums** has at least 1 zero or **ham_sums** is zero.

> spam_sums = np.log(spam_sums)

**spam_sums** has at least 1 zero or **spam_sums** is zero.

Comment: That is what I have data_size = len(data)
            ham = 0  # 
            spam = 1 

            for test in data:
                if test[0] == 0:
                    ham += 0
                else:
                    spam += 1

Comment: So ham is integer. But you are not changing its value. ham is still zero. You are adding zero to ham: ham += 0 

np.log(0) will give RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log

Comment: @XIUJY1111 I edited my answer.

Comment: Got it!! Thank you Now my Running time is only on the sums 

RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  ham_sums = np.log(ham_sums) and ivide by zero encountered in log
  spam_sums = np.log(spam_sums)

Comment: Not on the class anymore

Comment: @XIUJY1111 You can refer to my answer for the remaining warnings.